# iOS: How safe is serializing objects for data persistence on applicationWillTerminate? Any chance that the serialization will not complete?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I understand that you generally serialize objects for data persistence using the NSCoder protocol on applicationWillTerminate. Is there any good chance that this serialization will not complete though? I.e. the battery is about to die, so the app quits, and before the serialization can complete, the battery totally runs out.

I'm creating an app where the process for the user to add a new object (like a financial record) is pretty involved. Therefore, a failure to serialize the object would be pretty annoying because the recreation of that object would be a bit time consuming. Should I therefore do the serialization immediately after the user clicks the "Save" button, or can I be certain that the serialization will complete 99.9% of the time on applicationWillTerminate?

On a similar note, if I am having this data synced to a server, will my app have enough time to do this syncing on applicationDidEnterBackground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For applications that do not opt out of multitasking (by setting `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in the Info.plist), `applicationWillTerminate:` will not always be called, you should do your serialization in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` instead.

The most significant risk is that your serialization takes too long and the watchdog daemon kills your app before it finishes. This will happen if your serialization is taking more than about 5 seconds, which could very well happen if you serialize large objects.

Comment: I would add that it may be better to serialize data as it comes, unless you have a reason not to. This is all about the sensitivity of your data vs performance of your app. (How much time is spent saving while the app runs, vs how much time is spent saving when the app closes.)

Comment: @omz: Could you give me a sense of what a "large object" is? My objects are generally going to be arrays of other objects. And those "other objects" will have perhaps 10 pieces of data--mostly strings, but one image as well. I imagine that at a maximum, those arrays will hold roughly 100 objects of this nature.

Comment: @Moshe: I realize that, when the time comes, performance tests will be very helpful (i.e. how long does it take if I re-serialize one of my arrays every time a new object is added to it).

Comment: Still hoping to get a sense of what a "large" object is.

Comment: There is no definitive answer to that. You have to test how long it takes to serialize your object; this does not only depend on the pure size of it, but also on how it's being serialized. A JPEG image for example might be small when written to disk, but has a high CPU cost for the compression. Another important point to consider is whether your objects will all be (more or less) the same or if there are cases (user input?) where there's significantly more data to serialize.